# Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Me aparece el error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
>           at Object.success (Index.html:60)
>           at c (jquery.min.js:3)
>           at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:3)
>           at k (jquery.min.js:5)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.min.js:5)

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
function initMap() {

  $.get('http://iotserver1.dis.eafit.edu.co/weather/aarroyaveb', function(datos) {
    var array = datos.split("Z");

    var matriz = new Array(array.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
      matriz[i] = array[i].split(",");
      console.log(matriz[i][0] + " " + matriz[i][1]);
    }

    var sumTemp = 0;
    var sumHumid = 0;
    var maxTemp = 0;
    var minTemp = 100;
    var maxHumid = 0;
    var minHumid = 100;
    for (var j = matriz.length - 7; j < matriz.length - 1; j++) {
      sumTemp += parseFloat(matriz[j][1]);
      sumHumid += parseFloat(matriz[j][2]);

      if (matriz[j][1] > maxTemp) {
        maxTemp = matriz[j][1];
      }

      if (matriz[j][1] < minTemp) {
        minTemp = matriz[j][1];
      }

      if (matriz[j][2] > maxHum) {
        maxHumid = matriz[j][2];
      }
      if (matriz[j][2] < minHum) {
        minHumid = matriz[j][2];
      }
    }
    var preTemp = sumTemp / 6;
    var preHumid = sumHumidH / 6;
    var TempAct = mat[mat.length - 2][1];
    var HumidAct = mat[mat.length - 2][2];

    document.getElementById("minTemp").innerHTML = "La temperatura minima encontrada es de: " + minTemp + "°";
    document.getElementById("maxTemp").innerHTML = "La temperatura maxima encontrada de: " + maxTemp + "°";
    document.getElementById("minHumid").innerHTML = "La humedad minima encontrada es de: " + minHum + "%";
    document.getElementById("maxHumid").innerHTML = "La humedad maxima encontradaes de: " + maxHum + "%";
    document.getElementById("preTemp").innerHTML = "La temperatura en una hora sera de : " + preT + "°";
    document.getElementById("preHumid").innerHTML = "La humedad en una hora sera de : " + preH + "%";
    document.getElementById("TempAct").innerHTML = "La temperatura actual es : " + TempAct + "°";
    document.getElementById("HumAct").innerHTML = "La humedad actual es de : " + HumidAct + "%";


  });

  var centroMapa = new google.maps.LatLng(6.1976, -75.5750);

  <!-- opciones del mapa -->
  var misOpciones = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: centroMapa
  };

  var mimapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), misOpciones);

  $.get('http://iotserver1.dis.eafit.edu.co/weather/getAllLastWeather', function(marcadores) {
    <!-- RECORRER TODO EL ARREGLO DE MARCADORES Y PINTARLOS EN EL MAPA -->
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < marcadores.length; i++) {
      <!-- Imagen del pin y tamaño, color etc etc  -->
      var pinColor = "58FA58";
      if (marcadores[i].temp < 23) {
        pinColor = "A22BC6";

      } else {
        if (marcadores[i].temp > 22 && marcadores[i].temp < 25) {
          pinColor = "2BC661";
        } else {
          if (marcadores[i].temp > 24) {
            pinColor = "FF0000";
          }
        }
      }

      var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
        new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
      var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
        new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(12, 35));

      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marcadores[i].latitude, marcadores[i].longitude);
      var marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: mimapa,
        icon: pinImage,
        shadow: pinShadow,
        title: marcadores[i].temp + ',' + marcadores[i].humid
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
         * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 70%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- actualizar en YOUR_API_KEY la clave propia generada
        API_KEY propia= AIzaSyAbm8qiSpsSof1X-n84c1uiI77G_vpi8QY -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAbm8qiSpsSof1X-n84c1uiI77G_vpi8QY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

<div id="info">
  <h1>IoT Weather Station - Visualizacion de datos</h1>
</div>
<div id="botones">
  <table width="802" border="1" align="center">
    <tr bgcolor="#0066FF">
      <td width="260" height="25">
        <div align="center">
          <a href="Index.html"><img src="../Documents/Archivos de pag web/Icono de mapa.jpg" alt="Mapa" width="32" height="32" border="0"></a><a href="Index.html">.</a></div>
      </td>
      <td width="260">
        <div align="center">
          <a href="../Documents/Archivos de pag web/Temper.html"><img src="../Documents/Archivos de pag web/Icono temp.jpg" alt="Temperatura" width="32" height="32" border="0"></a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="260">
        <div align="center"><img src="../Documents/Archivos de pag web/Icono humid.jpg" alt="Humedad" width="32" height="32"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="map">
  <h2 id="TempAct"></h2>
</div>

<div id="pie de pagina">
  <hr>
  <h3>Realizado por:</h3>
  Alejandro Arroyave Bedoya - Jhon Edinson Rodriguez Gutierrez<br> Jose Fidel Hoyos &Aacute;vila - Diego Andres Garc&iacute;a Henao
</div>
```

Comment: Intenta con cambiar el siguiente:
<!-- RECORRER TODO EL ARREGLO DE MARCADORES Y PINTARLOS EN EL MAPA -->
      for (var i = 0; i < marcadores.length; i++) {

Answer (score 1):

Segun vi en el codigo usabas

```
var TempAct = mat[mat.length - 2][1];
var HumidAct = mat[mat.length - 2][2];
```

y realmente `mat` no lo has definido. Tal vez te referias a `matriz`?